Solving for a linear equation from a nondimensionalisation
Whilst doing my homework I came across the following question and got particularly stumped at question c). I do not know how I could possibly derive a precise linear relationship. Any help?
When a drop of liquid hits a wetted surface a crown formation appears, as shown in
the figure (a) below. It has been found that the number of points N on the crown
depends on the speed U at which the drop hits the surface, the radius r and mass
density ρ of the drop, and the surface tension σ of the liquid making up the drop.
(a) Use dimensional reduction to determine the functional dependence of N on U,
r, ρ, and σ.
Answer: after some work I arrived at the following equation for N; N=f(σ/(rρU^2 ))
(b) The value of N has been measured as a function of the initial height h of the
drop and the results are shown in the figure (b) above. Express your answer in
part (a) in terms of h by writing U in terms of h and gravitational accelaration
constant g. Assume the drop starts with zero velocity.
Answer: Here I got to the equation N= f(σ/2rρgh)
(c) The data in figure (b) show an approximately linear dependence on h, specifically, N can be described as a linear function of h Use this, and your result
from part (b), to find the unknown function in part (a). In the experiments, r
= 3.6 mm, ρ = 1.1014 gm/cm3 and σ = 50.5 dyn/cm.
Answer: here is where I do not know how to even start, perhaps I should solve;
N=kh+c= f(σ/2rρgh)  or something similar? Yet I would not know how to start. Furthermore, I am lost as to whether I should use the experiment values given or not. Lastly, as a detail, the experiment data provides a positive correlation between height and N.
Edit:
What is provided above is the only information I have been given the pictures do not add much value I feat yet here they are;
enter image description here

The problem seems to require a figure which is not included.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Specifically I need to answer question c still yet I do not have a clue how to go about it.

Can you tell us what you've done so far on part c?  What went wrong?

If $N$ is a function of $(\sigma/(2r\rho g h))$ it is also a function of the reciprocal
$$N=g(\frac{2 r \rho g h}{\sigma})$$
You're given that the function is approximately linear:
$$N \approx A + B\times (\frac{2 r \rho g h}{\sigma}) = A + (\frac{2 r \rho g B}{\sigma})\times h$$
If you have $N$ vs $h$ data, plot or do a linear least-squares fit of the data using above equation to get the values of $A$ and $B$ from the intercept and slope, respectively.
